# QGIS Server: Project name shown as layer. No other layers are shown

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

I have installed QGIS Server on Ubuntu 14.04

I do get a valid WMS response trying to reach

http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Next step I've done is trying to add a *.qgs map file and loading it back in QGIS 2.18.

There should be 2 layers served as WMS in that particular project, however I only get to see one called identified by 0 which is also my project title...

How come my layers are not showing up ?

```
 <Layer queryable="1">
<Name>gisoost.be</Name>
<Title>Gisoost.be</Title>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:31370</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<westBoundLongitude>3.32657</westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude>3.53157</eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude>51.007</southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude>51.1356</northBoundLatitude>
</EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:31370" maxx="91244.8" minx="77053.8" maxy="203167" miny="189038"/>
</Layer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue  but on Windows and the OSGeo4W installation.
In my case it was due to the fact that I didn't save the login information to connect to the database in the qgis-project.

-> Make sure that your project file has access and proper rights for your data sources.